# RotateProgress bar didn't stop in gridview when images loaded in glide

Tags: android, gridview

hello everyone plz solve my issue im in trouble. im using a progressbar rotateprogress bar and it didnot invisble when images loaded. i also try the default progressbar but result in same.
here is my code.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
//ProgressDialog progressDialog;

String activity;
RotateLoading rotateLoading;
int count;
// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c,String v) {
    mContext = c;
    activity=v;
}

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;}

public int getCount() {

    return  mThumbIds.length;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public String getItemThumb1(int position) {

    return mThumbIds[position];

}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_gallery,parent,false);
        imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(380,480));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        rotateLoading=(RotateLoading)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rotateloading1);




    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    }
    String url;
    url=getItemThumb1(position);



    rotateLoading.start();

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
           // .placeholder(R.drawable.loadingimage)
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    rotateLoading.start();
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                    rotateLoading.stop();
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
    return convertView;
}

// Keep all Images in array
public String[] mThumbIds = {
        "http://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Wide-wallpaper-nature-480x800-In-Wallpaper-HD-1366x768-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "http://greenywallpapers.com/wallpapers/10/275050-nature-wallpapers-720x1280.jpg",
        "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-wallpaper-nature-480x800-For-Wallpapers-Image-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-wallpaper-nature-480x800-In-Windows-Wallpaper-Themes-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Highres-wallpaper-nature-480x800-About-Windows-7-Wallpaper-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "http://freewallpaper-background.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/M-3.jpg",
        "http://naturewallpaperfree.com/mobile/sky/nature-wallpaper-480x800-127-96fbd452.jpg",

};
```

}

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<com.victor.loading.rotate.RotateLoading
    android:id="@+id/rotateloading1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:loading_width="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:loading_color="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager? Why in else case you are inflating imageView again?

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how the Custom view RotateLoading works. So calling `rotateLoading.stop()` hides the view or not. So you can try making the visibility gone after `rotateLoading.stop()`

Add this after `rotateLoading.stop();`

```
rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: rotateloading.stop() hides the progressbar.

Comment: if i use default progressbar, that progressbar also not hide, when i call progressbar.setvisibility(View.Gone)

Comment: Then something with the glide callback

Comment: give me the solution what could i do. i want to show the progress bar during image loading.

Comment: glide callback call, i make a toast in onResourceReady() function, and its work.

Comment: I'll look into glide source code once I get sometime. Plus if you want quick work around instead of using a full lib for loader and stuff place an loader image as a place holder. which will be replaced once the image will be loaded.